# CoreApplication error in UWP

Tags: uwp, navigationview

I try to draw into my tittle bar the of my app the background using this code

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

And got this error

> 'CoreApplication' does not exist in the current context

Any suggestions please??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just  don't reference the correspondent namespace. [`CoreApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication) class is belong to namespace `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core`. Simply add the namespace using at the top of the code file as follows:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
```

When you hover on the error line, the Visual Studio will mentioned the potential fix.